How to fetch and execute a SQL file from an Azure DevOps repository on a VM?
I am working on an Azure DevOps pipeline where I need to fetch a SQL file (up5.sql) from the repository and execute it on a Virtual Machine (VM). The pipeline and the SQL file are in the same repository.

Current YAML Pipeline:
Here’s the YAML I currently use to execute SQL files already present on the VM:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Production'

  jobs:
  - deployment: RunPowerShellOnVM
    displayName: 'Run PowerShell Script on VM'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'  
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
            displayName: 'Run SQL Deployment Script on VM'
            inputs:
              Machines: $(Machine)
              UserName: $(UserName)
              UserPassword: $(UserPassword)
              InlineScript: |
                $dbplain = $(UserPassword)
                $dblist = C:\mybin\bin\mysql.exe -u myuser -p"$dbplain" -e 'show databases;'

                foreach ($dbname in $dblist) {
                  if ($dbname.ToLower().Contains('prod')) {
                    Write-Host "Skipping Database: $dbname"
                  } else {
                    Write-Host "Updating $dbname..."
                    C:\Sites\UpdatePackage\sqlRunDeployment.cmd $dbplain $dbname
                  }
                }

What I Want to Achieve:
Instead of using a hardcoded SQL file already present on the VM, I want to:

Fetch the SQL file (up5.sql) from the repository during pipeline execution.
Execute the SQL file directly on the VM using the mysql command.

Challenges:

Fetching the SQL File:

How can I fetch the SQL file from the repository during pipeline execution?


Temporary Execution:

I want to execute the SQL file on the VM without permanently copying it there.



Desired YAML Pipeline:
Here’s an idea of what I want to achieve:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Production'

  jobs:
  - deployment: RunPowerShellOnVM
    displayName: 'Run SQL Script from Repo on VM'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'  
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self #getting issue in this 
            displayName: 'Checkout Repository'

          - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
            displayName: 'Run SQL File on VM'
            inputs:
              Machines: $(Machine)
              UserName: $(UserName)
              UserPassword: $(UserPassword)
              InlineScript: |
                $sqlFile = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Batch\up5.sql"
                $dbplain = $(UserPassword)
                C:\mybin\bin\mysql.exe -u myuser -p"$dbplain" --database=mydb < $sqlFile


Questions:

How can I fetch the SQL file from the repository during pipeline execution?
Is it possible to directly execute the file on the VM without permanently storing it there?


"How can I fetch the SQL file from the repository during pipeline execution?" - you use the checkout task to configure how the pipeline checks out source code. Which issues are you facing, any error message?
And what kind of repository are you trying to checkout? Azure Repos Git? GitHub? Other? Is the repository in the same Azure DevOps project or a different one?
See Limit job authorization scope.

I don't know how to copy a particular file from repo and then run that using PowerShellOnTargetMachines task ? @RuiJarimba

You need to checkout the file, not copy it. Could you please provide the details I asked for?

@Ranjan checkout: self should be add as the first step to pull down the repository, including the up5.sql file.

Also, use Test-Path to ensure the SQL file exists in the expected location before attempting to execute it. This avoids errors if the file is missing.

@Ranjan Your path should matches to the repository structure like $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Batch\up5.sql . If the file is in a different directory, update the path accordingly.

Thanks @RuiJarimba for the thoughtful and supportive comment regarding the question.

Using the PowerShellOnTargetMachines task you can copy a specific file from the repository and execute it on a VM.

Before that you need to Checkout the repository in the pipeline to make the file available. Copy the file from the repository to the target VM. Execute the file (in this case, the SQL script) on the target VM.

Thanks @RuiJarimba for the thoughtful comment and the insightful questions you raised.
Use PowerShell to copy the file from the pipeline workspace to the target VM.
YAML Pipeline:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Production'

  jobs:
  - deployment: RunPowerShellOnVM
    displayName: 'Run PowerShell Script on VM'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'  
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self  # Checkout the repository (this will pull all files, including SQL)

          - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
            displayName: 'Copy and Run SQL File on VM'
            inputs:
              Machines: $(Machine)
              UserName: $(UserName)
              UserPassword: $(UserPassword)
              InlineScript: |
                # Define the path of the SQL file from the repository
                $sqlFile = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Batch\up5.sql"  # Adjust based on your repo structure
                
                # Path on the target VM where the SQL file will be copied
                $targetFilePath = "C:\temp\up5.sql"
                
                # Copy the SQL file from pipeline workspace to the VM
                Copy-Item -Path $sqlFile -Destination $targetFilePath -Force
                
                # Check if the file is successfully copied
                if (Test-Path $targetFilePath) {
                    Write-Host "SQL file copied successfully to: $targetFilePath"
                    
                    # Run the SQL file on the target VM using MySQL
                    $dbPlain = $(UserPassword)
                    $mysqlCommand = "C:\mybin\bin\mysql.exe -u myuser -p'$dbPlain' --database=mydb < $targetFilePath"
                    Write-Host "Executing SQL file..."
                    
                    # Execute the SQL file
                    Invoke-Expression $mysqlCommand
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Failed to copy the SQL file."
                    exit 1  # Exit with error code if the file isn't copied
                }

In the above pipeline YAML, the repository that is being used is Azure Repos Git, as indicated by the checkout: self task

$targetFilePath = "C:\temp\up5.sql" This is the path on the target VM where the SQL file will be copied.

The powershell script in the pipeline will copy the SQL file from the pipeline's workspace to the target VM and execute it. The Invoke-Expression cmdlet runs the MySQL command.


Pipeline executed using the mysql command (up5.sql):

